# pack frame to bottom right of GUI

Tags: tcl

How could I use the options for the pack geometry manager to pack a frame to the bottom right of my GUI ? I've tried using,

```
pack -side bottom -anchor se
```

However, this simply packs it in relation to the parent frame, instead I want it to be packed to the bottom right relative to the window itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs say, `pack` assigns space around the edges of a (rectangular) cavity. There are only four "places" for the child to be placed at. You can, however, use pack in two steps:

```
pack [frame .f] -side bottom -expand yes -fill x
```

Get a parcel of space from the bottom edge, and tell the child to expand within it along the x axis.

```
pack [button .f.b -text X] -side right -in .f
```

Pack a button inside the frame, assigning it space along the right edge of the frame's space.

The `pack` geometry manager is a bit finicky. Maybe `grid` is more helpful for you.

Documentation:
[button (widget)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/button.htm),
[frame (widget)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/frame.htm),
[grid](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/grid.htm),
[pack](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/pack.htm)